# Share Spring OAuth2 client session cookie with SPA (React or Angular)

Tags: reactjs, angular, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

In  specification for [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) (React or Angular) at page 7 for the case when we have backend (BFF) we can see that at the end of the flow:

*The application server then keeps the access token and refresh token
stored internally, and creates a separate session with the browser-
based app via a traditional browser cookie (H).*

I use **spring-security-oauth2-client** and new **spring-security-oauth2-autorization-server** how I can create *separate session with the browser-based app via a traditional browser cookie* a the end of the flow? Or I have to share **sessionId** with my React or Angular application? But how I can do this?

Comment: I think [this video](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) from the Spring Security team will help you. It covers an example using the Spring Authorization Server with a SPA.

Comment: This is a great video it really helps could answer not in comment so I'll mark that you answered this question?